# Can I specify a min Dub or DMD version?

Tags: d, dmd, dub

People keep trying to build my project with old versions of Dmd and Dub (0.9.2 instead of 1.0.0) and it does not work. Can I specify in the dub.json file the min required dub version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. See [this issue](https://github.com/dlang/dub/issues/863) for more details. Please make noise there ;-)

Two ideas how to workaround around this for now.

### 1) Use static if in the main statement

```d
int main()
{
   static if (__VERSION__ < 2069)
   {
       pragma(msg, "Your DMD version is outdated. Please update");
       return 1;
   }
   ...
}
```

2) Use `preGenerateCommands = ['rdmd checkversions.d']`

```d
int main()
{
    import std.process : execute;
    import std.stdio : writeln;
    auto ver = execute(["dub", "--version"]);
    if (ver.status != 0)
    {
        writeln("Error: no dub installation found.");
    }
    else
    {
        import std.conv : to;
        import std.regex : ctRegex, matchFirst;
        auto ctr = ctRegex!`version ([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)`;
        auto r = ver.output.matchFirst(ctr);
        assert(r.length == 4, "version not found");
        int major = r[1].to!int, minor = r[2].to!int, patch = r[3].to!int;
        if (major < 2)
        {
            writeln(minor);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't realize you could use preGenerateCommands to run a command. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These days dub allows you to specify toolchain requirements. See https://dub.pm/package-format-json.html#toolchain-requirements

In `dub.json` you could do:

```
{
    "name": "my-package",
    "toolchainRequirements": {
        "dub": ">=1.14.0",
        "frontend": ">=2.069",
        "gdc": "no"
    }
}
```